# framework7: npm ERR! missing script: serve on package.json

Tags: frontend, html-framework-7

I added serve keyword inside package.json with localhost:8080 as it's value but it wont work. I tried using localhost ip address instead of "localhost" still got error.

On my package.json

```
{
  "name": "package-lock",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "framework7": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "serve":"localhost:8080",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```